# Publishing WFA in Visual Studio - target framework problems

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I've created a windows form app and now I want to publish it. This app is going to be used by my clients so it's going to run on different PCs. I publish my app by the main way in visual studio but when I run the .exe file on other PC (I'm simulating my clients PCs with this one) I get the .NET framework error that requires version 4.5.2! I don't want using my app becomes complicated & I don't want to force my clients to install .NET 4.5.2.

> > I need to target the .NET framework version 4.5.2 for using some features like "Tasks" so I can't target other versions.

I have some questions:

1. Which version of .NET is better to target for supporting most of clients?
2. Can I use something like portable versions for solving this? If not, what is the exact solution?

what do you suggest?

Comment: What version of Windows are your clients running this on? You need to target the "lowest common denominator" for the .NET framework version...

Comment: @RonBeyer mostly 8.1 and 10

Comment: Both 8.1 and 10 include .NET 4.5.1, you should be able to target that version and have it work.

Comment: @RonBeyer Do these versions support "Task" features?

Comment: It should, but only you can tell if 4.5.1 will work in your application. Change the framework, recompile, and run your tests to verify.

Comment: @RonBeyer So after verifying that, there is no way to support the lower versions?

Comment: You can't target multiple frameworks at the same time if that is what you are asking. You can dial the framework version back until something breaks, that will be the lowest your code supports without refactoring.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks a lot...:)

Comment: You could create a NSIS (Nullsoft) installer for your app that will install the dot net framework you need automatically if it is not already present on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found the exact solution according to @RonBeyer's comments.

> Windows 10 & 8.1 include .NET framework 4.5.1, so the lowest common denominator is ver4.5.1 for win8.1 & 10.

We can define the lowest common denominators by searching the official pages.

one common problem that may cause the error after changing the version of .NET framework is the problem of references. You'll may have problem after switching to lower versions with references like "MySql.Data"; So you need to change the version of some references to!

for example, for .NET framework 4.5.1 MySql.Data 6.9 is compatible but for .NET framework 4.5.2 the compatible versions are 8 versions.